# Acts as taggable not migrating because I have another tags model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to migrate acts_as_taggable to install it, but, since I already have a table called "tags", for photo tagging, it will collapse and wont migrate.

How can I change the name for the table acts_as_table creates? Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the docs at http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/3.4.1/frames

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
end
```

Just use the second line with your new Tag model name

Comment: My question is about installation, when migrating. Acts_as_taggable has hardcoded "tags" in their migrations, so I think its not possible. :(

Comment: you are right, the tags table is hardcoded... Then I think kyou have to create those tables "manually" (by setting up your own migration)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by renaming all of my Tag table + columns, and replacing every "Tag" call in my code.

Patience!!!

Thanks Fer